# VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString encoding to use for email generation

Tags: java, spring, email, velocity, mime

With Spring 3.0.5, I can generate emails by calling `VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(VelocityEngine velocityEngine, String templateLocation, Map model)`. This method generates a string that is fully compliant with MIME mail.

With Spring 3.2.11, that method is unsupported: one must use `VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngine velocityEngine, String templateLocation, String encoding, Map model, Writer writer)` with an additional `encoding` parameter.

Being a mailing context, I tried `org.apache.commons.codec.CharEncoding.US_ASCII` (which equals to `US-ASCII`) but it totally break my mails. All clients I tried (Outlook web mail, Outlook 2013, Windows 8's Mail) don't see subject and display all the MIME parts like the following:

```
------=_Part_0_1846461141.1413184892265
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="----=_Part_1_249771572.1413184892276"

------=_Part_1_249771572.1413184892276
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="----=_Part_2_861087694.1413184892311"

------=_Part_2_861087694.1413184892311
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

(Look at UTF-8!)

The question is: what is the **correct** way to invoke `mergeTemplateIntoString` with encoding argument?

Comment: I eventually switched to FreeMarker, just to let you know